# Python and Excel - dropdown formula

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm working on automatizing one report using Python.
In general I have around 20 excel files (.xlsx and .xlms) that I filter base on some criteria and then copy&paste to final report. At the end I dropdown/autofill formulas in the final report (from first row till end) - I assume it will save some time in preparing report.

Is below code (version 1) best way of dropdown/autofill formula? I need of course keep reference updates (meaning if I change cell, forumla updates -> AO11, AO12, AO13 ect).
I've tested also another approach (version 2) but then I receive error in excel and all formulas are deleted...

```
#Version 1
# Loop over each row in the range
for row in range(start_row, end_row + 1):
    # Adjust the formula for each row
    adjusted_formula = formula_AP10.replace("10", str(row))  # Update the row reference
    adjusted_formula = adjusted_formula.replace("AO10", f"AO{row}")  # Update the AO10 reference   
    adjusted_formula = adjusted_formula.replace("AN10", f"AN{row}")  # Update the AN10 reference
                    
    # Set the adjusted formula to the current cell in column AP
    MPV1[f"AP{row}"].value = adjusted_formula      



#Version 2
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Load the workbook
wb = load_workbook('_MAT_TEMPLATE_Python.xlsx')
ws = wb["Material prices"]

# Get the total number of rows based on column A
total_rows = sum(1 for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=7, max_col=1, max_row=ws.max_row, values_only=True) if row[0])

# Apply formulas in column B
for row in range(7, 7 + total_rows):
    # Generate the formula for column B
    formula = f'=VLOOKUP($A{row},"Master data"!$A:$H,2,0)'

    # Apply the formula to the cell
    ws.cell(row=row, column=2, value=formula)

# Save the workbook
wb.save("_MAT_TEMPLATE_Python.xlsx")



#Error that I receive:
recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
<logFileName>error148000_01.xml</logFileName>
<summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\Users\HP\MHL project\_MAT_TEMPLATE_Python.xlsx'</summary>
<removedRecords summary="Following is a list of removed records:">
<removedRecord>Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet23.xml part</removedRecord>
</removedRecords>
</recoveryLog>

#Version 3
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.formula.translate import Translator

# Load the workbook
wb = load_workbook('_MAT_TEMPLATE_Python.xlsx')
ws = wb["Material prices"]

# Get the total number of rows in the worksheet
total_rows = ws.max_row

# Original formula
orig_formula = "VLOOKUP($A7;'Master data'!$A:$H;2;0)"

# Apply formulas in column B
for row in range(8, total_rows+1):
    # Replace the row number in the formula
    new_formula = orig_formula.replace("$A7", f"$A{row}")
    ws[f"B{row}"] = new_formula

# Save the workbook
wb.save("_MAT_TEMPLATE_Python.xlsx")
```

Comment: Seems strange to reduce the row count by 7 then re-add it in the range count. To fix the error in Version 2 change your use of single/double quotes around `formula = f"=VLOOKUP($A{row},'Master data'!$A:$H,2,0)"`

Answer (score 0):

If you like you can use the translator
Enter the first formula in cell 'B7' then translate to the rest of the cells in Column B.
The [Openpyxl Translator](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formula.html?highlight=translate#translating-formulae-from-one-location-to-another) allows you to translate a formula at any cell to another wherever on the Sheet.

```
#Version 3
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.formula.translate import Translator

# Load the workbook
wb = load_workbook('_MAT_TEMPLATE_Python.xlsx')
ws = wb["Material prices"]

# Get the total number of rows based on column A
total_rows = sum(1 for row in ws.iter_rows(max_col=1, max_row=ws.max_row, values_only=True) if row[0])

# Generate the formula for column B
orig_formula = "=VLOOKUP($A7,'Master data'!$A:$H,2,0)"
orig_cell = 'B7'
ws[orig_cell] = orig_formula

# Apply formulas in column B
for row in range(8, total_rows+1):

    dst_cell = f"B{row}"
    # Apply the formula to the cell translating from cell B7
    ws[dst_cell] = Translator(orig_formula, origin=orig_cell).translate_formula(dst_cell)

# Save the workbook
wb.save("_MAT_TEMPLATE_Python.xlsx")
```

Comment: I've tried above solution but I receive below information after launching script 
C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py:300: UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed
 warn(msg)
Additionally when I open excel I receive info that file needs to be recovered and in the end no formulas are added.

Comment: Make sure you fixed the formula as noted in the comment to your question. It is corrected in the code example above. You can; 1) Comment out the loop and ensure that just the formula in 'B7' is correct as this is the base formula. 2) Remove the '=' from the start of the formula so its just text written to the cell and check the formula text is correct for each and written to the correct cells. Then reinsert the '=' back to see if the formula works as expected. The warning also suggests that you have DV in sheet so you issue may be related to that.

Comment: If I use your code without "=" then still there are no updates in cells after using script.
I've made another version of code (see "Version 3" in main post). If I use scrip witohut "=" then code works fine. If I try with full formula, again I receive info that file needs to be recovered and in the end no formulas are added -_-

Comment: Did you check that the formula in B7 works? If Excel is rejecting the formulas there is something wrong with them. So if you removed the prefix '=' then open the Excel file and re-add what does Excel say about the formula? All Translator does is replicate the formulas to another cells and translates the references, even if references were wrong the formula should still be accepted. The formulas give no errors for me and I have no issue after opening the Excel file, all formulas are created and exist in the sheet. Maybe you should try a blank sheet/workbook for testing.